# When capturing Django named groups from a URL, how not to decode them?

Tags: django, urldecode, named-parameters

I have the following url pattern defined (simplified for clarity) that captures the asset key (an arbitrary string) from a url:

```
url(r'^assets/(?P<key>.+)$', views.AssetDetail.as_view())
```

And my view is defined like this:

```
def get(self, request, key):
    ...
```

This becomes interesting when I make these two requests:

1. /assets/some+key
2. /assets/some%2Bkey

Both requests result in the view's `key` parameter containing the string "some+key".  So, it looks like url decoding happens when the named group is captured and passed to the view, resulting in two different keys getting the same value.  This is a problem because I need to distinguish between these two keys.

How do I get the key to be passed into my view raw and **not** decoded?

Comment: Are you always going to be getting two keys like this, or will it be a variable amount of keys?

Comment: @Jens Astrup, this is just an example.  I can have many assets with a variety of keys.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be using url kwargs at all - there should be one value per key in the url or you'll run into the issue you're having now. A variable amount of arguments should be kept in the query parameters: `website.com/assets?some=value&key=value2` which you can access with `request.GET['some']`.